# Interpretation of plots for outlier detection in healthcare

Tags: clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution, bic, anomaly-detection

Christy et al. propose cluster-based approach to outlier detection as part of the preprocessing step. However, I don't think the plots are very interpretable. The authors use the R mclustbic function to determine BIC at different cluster sizes using GMMs - what is this supposed to show?

I would think the plots are designed to illustrate effectiveness of their outlier detection methods, but this fact is not obvious to me.

Thoughts on this?

[link to paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050915005591)

Comment: Horribly bad paper. Ignore it.